# Running OptaPlanner on the module path

Tags: java, gradle, java-9, optaplanner, java-module

I would like to make my OptaPlanner project run on the module path.

I created an example repository ([mwkroening/optaplanner-modulepath-example](https://github.com/mwkroening/optaplanner-modulepath-example)) based on the cloud balancing demo in the docs.

The example project is running well on the classpath but there is an issue I can't workaround when trying to make it run on the module path. You can see the progress so far in PR [#1](https://github.com/mwkroening/optaplanner-modulepath-example/pull/1).

The scoreDrl specified in the [solverConfig.xml](https://github.com/mwkroening/optaplanner-modulepath-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/io/github/mwkroening/optaplannermodulepathexample/cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml) fails to load with the following exception:

```sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The scoreDrl (io/github/mwkroening/optaplannermodulepathexample/cloudBalancingScoreRules.drl) does not exist as a classpath resource in the classLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@7c16905e).
    at org.optaplanner.core@7.18.0.Final/org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildDroolsScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:519)
    at org.optaplanner.core@7.18.0.Final/org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:351)
    at org.optaplanner.core@7.18.0.Final/org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:255)
    at org.optaplanner.core@7.18.0.Final/org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:61)
    at io.github.mwkroening.optaplannermodulepathexample/io.github.mwkroening.optaplannermodulepathexample.App.main(App.java:14)
```

I got a similar exception before when calling [SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.18.0.Final/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/solver/SolverFactory.html#createFromXmlFile-java.io.File-).
My workaround for that problem was instead calling:

```java
SolverFactory.createFromXmlInputStream(
  App.class.getResourceAsStream("cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml"));
```

I looked at [PLANNER-883](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-883) and [psiroky/optaplanner-cloudbalancing-jdk9](https://github.com/psiroky/optaplanner-cloudbalancing-jdk9), but I think a classpath resource was used in that case and not one on the module path.

How could I resolve this issue?
Perhaps I should open an issue instead of posting this here, right?

Comment: Very interesting experiment. See also my experiment with [running OptaPlanner on Graal](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/optaplanner-dev/KXw-9GarGIk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an overloaded method of every `SolverFactory.createFrom*(...)` that accepts a classloader: `SolverFactory.createFrom*(..., classloader)`. That class loader isn't just used for loading the XML resources, but also the DRL resource.

So try:

```
SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("/.../cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml",
    App.class.getClassLoader())
```

I haven't tested this out yet myself, but if it works, I'd love to see this added to [the "jigsaw" section in the manual](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-docs/src/main/asciidoc/Integration/Integration-chapter.adoc#integrationWithJPMS) (PR welcome :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I had to open the package in `module-info.java` and add `--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=org.drools.core`.
Supplying a class loader is not even necessary now.
One thing that bothers me though, is that I can't find the module I have to open my package to. So now it's `opens [...];`, but I would really like something like `opens [...] to org.optaplanner.core;`. This way I would not be forced to open my package to everybody. I tried every module name, I could think of, but I didn't find the one.